# How to update an item in a redis list using servicestack typed client?

Tags: redis, servicestack

Piece of my code

```
var redislist = client.As<MyModel>().Lists["key_of_list"];
var m = redislist.SingleOrDefault(p => p.member_id == request.member_id);
m.email = request.email;
```

So as you can see, I've got the item m, and I can also update the item. Question is how to do next if I want to update it and save it back to the redis list?

Should I just remove it and add a new item like

```
redislist.Remove(old_item);
var new_item = new MyModel();
new_item.email = request.email;
redislist.Add(new_item);
```

And btw, what's the difference between redis.append and redis.add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to use `IRedisTypedClient<T>.SetItemInList` [which internally uses `lset` command](http://redis.io/commands/lset) instead of removing and adding the item.

In the other hand, adding is using `set (i.e. setting a key with some value overwriting it if it exists) and`append` is almost the same with an important difference [(from Redis official documentation)](http://redis.io/commands/append):

> If key already exists and is a string, this command appends the value
>   at the end of the string. If key does not exist it is created and set
>   as an empty string, so APPEND will be similar to SET in this special
>   case.